# Selecting the newest date?

Tags: powershell

I'm wanting to query a list of servers and emailing me the last date updates were installed.

```
$date = (Get-HotFix | select installedon).installedon
```

Gets me all the dates updates were installed I only need the last time updates were installed. How do I get just the newest date?

Comment: `$LastInst = (Get-Hotfix).InstalledOn| Sort| Select -Last 1`

Answer (score 7):

you're probably looking for something like this?

```
Get-Hotfix | Sort InstalledOn -Descending | Select -First 1
```

sort the list and select the top one, you could also use

```
Get-Hotfix | Sort InstalledOn | Select -Last 1
```

there's no difference between the two.